# Parsing XML using xml2js in Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa skill using Lambda Function that serves the data via a web service. The web service returns XML data, so I am using xml2js (which is supported).

The returned XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DailySummary>
  <day dayOfWeek="Sunday" Date="04/22/2018" attribute1="test1" attribute2="test3" />
</DailySnapshot>
```

How do you access the attributes of the  element?

In an index.js file, I added the following code under

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
 var extractedData = "";
 var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DailySummary><day dayOfWeek="Sunday" Date="04/22/2018" attribute1="test1" attribute2="test3" />   </DailySnapshot>';
 parseString(xml, function (err, result) 
 {
   if(err) throw err;
   extractedData = result['DailySummary']['day'][0].$.type
 });        

callback(null,extractedData);    
};
```

I get an error:

```
Function Logs:
START RequestId: b9c528f7-5cfc-11e8-a617-211b3668a43f Version: $LATEST
2018-05-21T13:41:56.667Z    b9c528f7-5cfc-11e8-a617-211b3668a43f    Error: Unexpected close tag
Line: 0
Column: 153
```

I am a newbie to node.js so pardon my ignorance and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the callback call into the `parseString` callback.

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
 var extractedData = "";
 var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DailySummary><day dayOfWeek="Sunday" Date="04/22/2018" attribute1="test1" attribute2="test3" />   </DailySnapshot>';
 parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
   if(err) throw err;
   extractedData = result['DailySummary']['day'][0].$.type;
   callback(null,extractedData);
 });
};
```

The only place that you have assurance that the result data exists is into the callback, so everything that you want to do with it must be done into the callback.

Comment: The code executes successfully but the response is null. Shouldn't the result['DailySummary']['day'][0].$.type return Sunday?

Comment: Not working with the latest version xml2js not found